# Simple request with OpenLayers/PgAdmin on HTML page

Tags: javascript, html, postgresql, openlayers

I have an issue with Openlayers, i want to do a simple request ( for exemple : SELECT * FROM dvf WHERE idmutation = 1 ) and display the data on index.html below the map on the red circle when i click on the button test [image].

I tried some AJAX but i didnt manage to do it , the main issue for me is that the index is on HTML and not PHP, sadly cant change this. Im using Javascript and i want to add the code here : [image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch), the standard code goes like:

```js
fetch('http://example.com/movies.json')
  .then((response) => {
    return response.json();
  })
  .then((data) => {
    console.log(data);
  });
```

Ok I didn't realize you were using PHP for database, if you want to query something from the database with JavaScript you're gonna need an endpoint like `/grab`, or you might be able to point the request to another PHP page in which you do the request and return it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i'm used to PHP so i prefer using it but if there is a better solution than using a PHP page then I want to try.